# Ionic custom authentication endpoint documentation/example using WCF

Tags: wcf, authentication, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework, jwt

I'm looking for a more detailed description of what is required for my endpoint for Ionic's custom Authentication. [Ionic Custom Authentication](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/custom-authentication).
If possible a sample project or a tutorial to follow.
I've looked extensively however, either my googling skills have died or there's nothing more out there (from what I can see).

I've tested this with the 'basic' setting, but need to connect with my own endpoint through ionic. As seen below:

```
    Ionic.Auth.login('custom', options, details).then(function (success) {
        console.log('Ionic Login Success:');
        console.log(success);
    }, function (failure) {
        console.error('Ionic Login Failure: ' + failure.response.body.error.message);
    });
```

**Some Background:**
I have a Ionic Cordova app that can connect/authenticate to my WCF Web API (by doing some hack of a login/authentication process) and then retrieving data for the logged in user. I need to convert this to Ionic Auth.
PS. I have no Experience with JWT and have gotten as far as installing the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt Package on my WCF service.

Any information is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

> I know the question lacks some details but I can't give more until I know more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ionic team added three sample projects that demonstrate the custom-auth backends. Those three are **express**, **flask** and **golang**. I managed to set up a backend for CakePHP 2.6.x by looking at the [server part](https://github.com/driftyco/custom-auth-examples/blob/master/express/server.js) of the backend.

You should be able to put together something as it is not magic. I added some PHP snipplets that should show you how you can make it in your specific language:

- Get the `redirect_uri` parameter from the url and save it
- Get the `state` parameter from the url and save it
- Get the `token` parameter from the url and save it
- Save your shared secret into a variable
- Decode the JWT token using HS256 algorithm

The structure of the decoded token should look like this:

```
"decoded_array": {
   "data": {
     "password": "someString",
     "email": "some@email.com"
   },
   "exp": 1457731231,
   "app_id": "your app id"
}
```

- Now check if you have a user in your database (do the authentication)
- If authentication was not successful, return a UnauthorizedException (401)
- If the authentication was successful, create a new variable called `payload`. This should contain your `user_id` from your database:

  ```
  $payload = array('user_id' => $user['User']['id']);
  ```
- Now encode payload with your `sharedSecret` string by creating a new JWT token:

`$outgoingToken = JWT::encode($payload, $sharedSecret);`

- Redirect back to ionic:

  $url = $redirectUri . '&token=' . $outgoingToken . '&state=' . $state . '&redirect_uri=https://api.ionic.io/auth/integrations/custom/success'; $this->redirect($url);

---

Check out this Github-project: https://github.com/driftyco/custom-auth-examples

You can also check out my PHP implementation here: https://www.doonot.com/custom-auth-backend-for-ionic-auth-using-cakephp/

Comment: I followed you tutorial, which is pretty nice btw, and redirected with the php header("Location: $url") - the problem is that i get redirected in the app as well. so i see the "message": "You have successfully implemented custom authentication!" in the app as well

Comment: Just remove `&redirect_uri=https://api.ionic.io/auth/integrations/custom/success` from the `url`. This is only for debugging. After you remove it, you should be redirected to your app.

Comment: @doonot when returning a 401 for auth errors it just seems to open the in app browser and do nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to get one with laravel

Comment: @ballerz I posted part of a laravel 3 controller method in my question about a problem, similar to the one MattSull is describing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346272/how-to-handle-login-errors-with-ionic-custom-auth